# Rotinas entre forms diferentes em VB

Tags: vba, visual-basic-6

Boas, estou a fazer uma aplicação em VBA com 2 forms. No form1 tenho uma flexgrid que carrega registos de uma base de dados e no form 2 tenho uma textbox que introduz registo na mesma base de dados. O que quero fazer é ao clicar no botão de adicionar do form2 a grid do form1 atualize automaticamente. Como faço para atualizar visto que se tratam de forms diferentes?

ps: Não posso ter botões no form1 para atualizar, tem que ser mesmo automaticamente após o clique no botão adicionar do form2.

Obrigado :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você precisa seria algo tipo:

```
//Form1
Public Sub Atualizar()
    MsgBox "Atualizado"
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim objForm2 As Form2

    Set objForm2 = New Form2

    Set objForm2.Formulario = Me

    objForm2.Show 1

    Set objForm2 = Nothing

End Sub

//Form2
Private m_objFormulario As Form1

Public Property Set Formulario(ByVal oValue As Form1)
    Set m_objFormulario = oValue
End Property

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Call m_objFormulario.Atualizar
    Unload Me
End Sub
```